# How to get the height of a div after its content is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

im trying to get the size of an `<img>` in the `<window>` by checking width and height of its container.

i used `.load()` to wait until the `<img>` is loaded.

On pageload the size is still 0.

I only get the correct height on resize.

What is wrong here?

EDIT: to get the correct  size i added `.contents()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').load(function(){   
        function size(){
            var height  = $('#size').contents()height();
            var width   = $('#size').contents().width();
            $('#size').find('p.size').remove();
            $('#size').append('<p class="size">' + height + '-' + width + '</p>');
        };
        $(window).load(size);
        $(window).resize(size);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you define a function, but you don't invoke it

place `size();` after `$(window).resize(size);`

EDIT: whole code with some improvements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function size(){
        var height = $('#size').height();
        var width = $('#size').width();
        $('#size').find('p.size').remove();
        $('#size').append('<p class="size">' + height + '-' + width + '</p>');
    }

    $(window).load(size);
    $(window).resize(size);
    $('img').load(size);
});
```

Comment: it gehts invoked...$(window).load(size);

Comment: @Gregor but both of those events fire before the AJAX request completes. You need to also call the function directly in the callback as pwolaq suggests

Comment: yes, on window resize as you stated - if you want to invoke it after load, place the code above as I suggested

Comment: sorry, im confused could you post an example?

Comment: Put `size();` right after `$(window).resize(size);`

Comment: @pwolaq ah, did not notice your edit. thats it. thank you!